# Reactjs - Isotope layout - using data-attributes to filter/sort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-isotope

I am trying to streamline the isotope handler in a react component -- I want to create filter options that would be like catergory[metal] or catergory[transition] -- and combo filters like catergory[metal, transition].

the sandbox for this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-tnih7

So like filterFns[ filterValue, "param2" ] -- how to push 2 params into the filter functions - rather than these fixed greaterThan50 -- a "greaterThan(50)", "greaterThan(5) -- this dynamic filtering type of handler "

[image]

latest sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-tnih7?file=/src/IstotopeWrapper.js
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ButtonGroup from '@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup';

import GenericForm from '../GenericForm/GenericForm';

import './IsotopeHandler.scss';


class IsotopeHandler extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.myRef = React.createRef();


      let items = [{
        "name": "Mercury",
        "category": "transition",
        "weight": "122",
        "symbol": "Hg",
        "number": 12,
        "custom": "a",
        "isgas": false
      }, {
        "name": "Tellurium",
        "category": "metal",
        "weight": "12",
        "symbol": "Te",
        "number": 232,
        "custom": "b",
        "isgas": false
      }, {
        "name": "Bismuth",
        "category": "rock",
        "weight": "2200.59",
        "symbol": "Bi",
        "number": 1666,
        "custom": "c",
        "isgas": false
      }, {
        "name": "Cadmium",
        "category": "metal",
        "weight": "1200",
        "symbol": "Cd",
        "number": 454,
        "custom": "d",
        "isgas": false
      }, {
        "name": "Bosim",
        "category": "gas",
        "weight": "100",
        "symbol": "Gs",
        "number": 454,
        "custom": "e",
        "isgas": true
      }, {
        "name": "xosim",
        "category": "gas",
        "weight": "100",
        "symbol": "xs",
        "number": 44,
        "custom": "f",
        "isgas": true
      }]

      this.state = { sortBy: 'original-order', items: items };

      this.onFilterHandler = this.onFilterHandler.bind(this);
      this.onSortHandler = this.onSortHandler.bind(this);
    }

    onSortHandler(sortValue){
      if(sortValue){
        console.log("sortValue", sortValue);
        let bool = this.state.bool;
        let options = { sortBy: sortValue };
        
        options = Object.assign(options, {
            sortAscending: (bool = !bool),
        });        

        this.setState({ bool: bool });
        this.setState({ sortBy: sortValue });

        this.state.iso.arrange(options);
      }
    }

    onFilterHandler(filterName, filterField, filterValue){

        var filterFns = {
          //match
          matches: function(itemElem) {
            var values = itemElem.getAttribute('data-'+filterField);
            return values.match(filterValue);
          },

          //greaterThan 
          greaterThan: function(itemElem) {
            var number = itemElem.getAttribute('data-'+filterField);
            return parseInt(number, 10) > filterValue;
          },

          //lessThan 
          lessThan: function(itemElem) {
            var number = itemElem.getAttribute('data-'+filterField);
            return parseInt(number, 10) < filterValue;
          }, 

          //Between 
          between: function(itemElem) {
            var number = itemElem.getAttribute('data-'+filterField);
            return parseInt(number, 10) > parseInt(filterValue.split(",")[0], 10) && parseInt(number, 10) < parseInt(filterValue.split(",")[1], 10);
          }, 

        };

        // use matching filter function
        let val = filterFns[filterName] || filterValue;

        this.state.iso.arrange({ filter: val });
    }

    submitFilterFormHandler(data){
      console.log("data now with parent", data);

      if(data){
        //open dialog box
        //console.log("this", this);
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        // init Isotope
        var iso = new Isotope(this.myRef.current, {
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
          getSortData: this.getCustomSortAttributes(this.state.items[0])
        });

        this.setState({ iso: iso });
        console.log("iso",iso);
    }

    getCustomSortAttributes(item){
      let keys = Object.keys(item);
      let dataObj = {};
      
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var obj = {
          [keys[i]]: '[data-'+keys[i]+']'
        }
        dataObj = {...obj, ...dataObj}
      }
      return dataObj;      
    }

    attributeGeneration(item){
      let keys = Object.keys(item);
      let dataObj = {};
      
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var obj = {
          ["data-"+keys[i]]: item[keys[i]]
        }
        dataObj = {...obj, ...dataObj}
      }
      return dataObj;
    }

    render() {


        var sorts = [{
          "label": "Original Order",
          "value": "original-order"
        },{
          "label": "Name",
          "value": "name"
        },{
          "label": "Symbol",
          "value": "symbol"
        },{
          "label": "Number",
          "value": "number"
        },{
          "label": "Weight",
          "value": "weight"
        },{
          "label": "Category",
          "value": "category"
        },{
          "label": "Custom",
          "value": "custom"
        }]


        let filters = [{
            "label": "show all",
            "params": {
              "filter": "showAll",
              "field": "",
              "value": "*"
            }
          },{
            "label": "number > 50",
            "params": {
              "filter": "greaterThan",
              "field": "number",
              "value": 50
            }
          },{
            "label": "number < 350",
            "params": {
              "filter": "lessThan",
              "field": "number",
              "value": 350
            }
          },{
            "label": "between- number < 350 && number < 600",
            "params": {
              "filter": "between",
              "field": "number",
              "value": "350,600"
            }
          },{
            "label": "metal category",
            "params": {
              "filter": "matches",
              "field": "category",
              "value": "metal"
            }
          },{
            "label": "metal transition",
            "params": {
              "filter": "matches",
              "field": "category",
              "value": "transition"
            }
          },{
            "label": "metal gas and transition",
            "params": {
              "filter": "matches",
              "field": "category",
              "value": "gas|transition"
            }
          },{
            "label": "isGas",
            "params": {
              "filter": "matches",
              "field": "isgas",
              "value": true
            }
          }]



        let initialFilterFormValues = {
          "manual": "type to filter"
        }

        let fieldsFilterForm = [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "label": "Manual Entry",
              "name": ["manual"],
              "options": []
            },
            {
              "type": "buttons",
              "label": "Sweets2",
              "name": ["sweets2"],
              "options": [
                {
                  "label": "Sherbert",
                  "value": "0"
                },
                {
                  "label": "Peach Jam",
                  "value": "1"
                },
                {
                  "label": "Almond Butter",
                  "value": "2"
                }
              ],
              //"validate": ["required"],
            }            
          ];

        let buttonsFilterForm = [
          /*{
            "label": "Submit3",
            "variant": "contained",
            "color": "primary",
            "type": "submit",
            "disabled": ["submitting"],
            "onClick" : null
          }*/
        ];


        return (
          <div 
            className={"isotope"}
          >

            <div className="button-group filters-button-group">
              <ButtonGroup variant="outlined" color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
              {                
                filters.map((item, j) => {
                  return(
                    <Button 
                      key={j} 
                      className="button" 
                      onClick={() => this.onFilterHandler(item.params.filter, item.params.field, item.params.value)}
                    >
                      {item.label}
                    </Button>
                  )
                })
              }
              {/*
              <Button className="button" data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</Button>
              <Button className="button" data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</Button>
              <Button className="button" data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</Button>
              */}
              </ButtonGroup>   
            </div>

            <div className="button-group sort-by-button-group">
              <ButtonGroup variant="outlined" color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                {                
                  sorts.map((item, j) => {
                    return(
                      <Button 
                        key={j} 
                        className="button" 
                        onClick={() => this.onSortHandler(item.value)}
                      >
                        {item.label}
                      </Button>
                    )
                  })
                }                
              </ButtonGroup>
            </div>


            {/*
            <GenericForm 
              initialValues={initialFilterFormValues} 
              fields={fieldsFilterForm}
              buttons={buttonsFilterForm}
              submitHandler={this.submitFilterFormHandler}
            />
            */}


            <div 
              className="grid" 
              ref={this.myRef}
            >
              {
                this.state.items.map((item, j) => {
                  return(
                    <div
                      key={j} 
                      className="grid-item"
                      {...this.attributeGeneration(item)}
                    >
                      <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                      <p>{item.weight}</p>
                      <p>{item.number}</p>
                      <p>{item.symbol}</p>
                      <p>{item.category}</p>
                    </div>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>

          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default IsotopeHandler;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you application you can stor filters inside an array and update filters array to either new filter (single filter mode) or push newly selected filter on top of existing filters list.

Take a look at updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-shadow-p7zx2) here.

First of all we are registering our filter method with Isotope:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // init Isotope
  var iso = new Isotope(this.myRef.current, {
    itemSelector: ".grid-item",
    layoutMode: "fitRows",
    getSortData: this.getCustomSortAttributes(this.state.items[0]),
    filter: this.filterData  // <- custom filter method
  });

  this.setState({ iso: iso });
  console.log("iso", iso);
}
```

Updated `onFilterHandler` and it takes 3 arguments

1. addFilter: boolean flag to indicate if new filter condition should be added or existing should be removed
2. filterCondition: a string condition or an array of conditions in form `rule|field|value`
3. type: string value that would be wither `AND` or `OR` to determine if all  conditions in type should be matched or any single should be matched

based on the areguments function either adds new filter or searches for existing one and removes it from global `filters` array.

```
getFilterObject(condition) {
  const conditionItems = condition.split("|");
  const filterName = conditionItems[0];
  const filterField = conditionItems[1];
  const filterValue = conditionItems[2];

  return {
    condition: condition,
    name: filterName,
    field: filterField,
    value: filterValue,
    filterFunc: this.filterFns[filterName]
  };
}

onFilterHandler(addFilter, filterCondition, type = "AND") {
  // use matching filter function
  // let val = filterFns[filterName] || filterValue;
  const filterObj = {
    type: type,
    filters: Array.isArray(filterCondition)
      ? filterCondition.map((cnd) => this.getFilterObject(cnd))
      : [this.getFilterObject(filterCondition)]
  };
  const existingFilters = this.filters.filter(
    (f) =>
      f.filters.length === filterObj.filters.length &&
      f.filters.every((f) =>
        filterObj.filters.some(
          (fObjFilter) => fObjFilter.condition === f.condition
        )
      )
  );

  if (addFilter && existingFilters.length === 0) {
    this.filters = [...this.filters, filterObj];
  } else if (!addFilter) {
    this.filters = this.filters.filter((f) => !existingFilters.includes(f));
  }

  this.state.iso.arrange();
}
```

newly added `filterData` function will be responsible for filtering data based on current filters list:

```
filterData(item) {
    if (this.filters.length <= 0) {
      return true;
    }

    const filterPredicate = (filterObj) => {
      return typeof filterObj.filterFunc === "function"
        ? filterObj.filterFunc(item, filterObj.field, filterObj.value)
        : filterObj.value === "*"
        ? true
        : item.classList.contains(filterObj.value);
    };

    for (let idx = 0; idx < this.filters.length; idx++) {
      const filterObj = this.filters[idx];
      const retVal =
        filterObj.type === "OR"
          ? filterObj.filters.some((fObjFilter) => filterPredicate(fObjFilter))
          : filterObj.filters.every((fObjFilter) =>
              filterPredicate(fObjFilter)
            );

      if (retVal) {
        return retVal;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that's not really what I mean -- instead of having buttons -- have actual checkboxes --- maybe even a mixture of inputs  buttons and checkboxes so its a combination of AND or OR

Comment: I was thinking like changing -- the params like this on a button - params: {
          filter: "matches&greaterthan",
          field: "category&number",
          value: "transition&10"
        }

Comment: Sure, the changes I made are in right direction to achieve that. When I will get a chance, I will take a further look in the evening.

Comment: maybe - the params needs to be an array - and that way it can pick up multiple filter settings to roll over -- params: [{filter: matches, field: category, value: transition}, {filter: greaterthan, field: number, value: 10}, {filter: matches, field: category, value: gas&chalk}]

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-tnih7?file=/src/IsotopePopClickEl.js  -- here is the latest work on this -- so you can see how I've pushed the items and filters/sorts -- so the isotope part is like an empty shell for other types of isotope modules/contents

Comment: so like you will see in the IstotopeWrapper --- there is a form fields object -- that has the label of the button, then the 3 pieces of information for filtering -- name of filter, field, value

Comment: So now you want to achieve combination filtering with structure you have, right?

Comment: yeah that's right -- probably need an array to capture combined filters

Comment: https://codepen.io/shainanigans-1472169587/pen/PWWQJW -- just saw this has checkboxes - cause I would like to make a form components --using sliders - and checkboxes etc..

Comment: Not completely sure if this is all you want, but I have updated answer and codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-keldysh-i8748

Comment: -- this is nice - but what I mean is -- you got these -- object params in the fields ---  "matches|category|marketing" //rule/field/value --- but you may need an array to handle MULTI FIlters -- so you could have this category===marketing and number > 50 -- so it starts to make a multi-filter combo on different attributes

Comment: See that is the part I still don't understand as it is already using an array to hold filters. May you mean an array of conditions where each condition it self holds an array of simple condition. Would that be correct?

Comment: -- well no that's what I mean -- so you can make a button called - "Marketing and over 50"

Comment: but -- that's just to make buttons -- its the logic handling of the isotope selectors to be able to ring around different attributes and conditions - --- you may want some buttons and may want some checkboxes and may want a slider or a toggle you see to control the isotope that way

Comment: How complex your condition will get? I mean will it be just few && conditions or will be more complex than that?

Comment: well - world's the oyster --category- marketing, number>50, isOnline - true

Comment: that's why -- the field setting - label/value - could be an array - to do a combo of filters

Comment: Take a look at updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-keldysh-i8748
May be this is all you want. Specifically look at last 2 conditions they are checkbox but could be anything and filter logic will still work.

Comment: you able to add more comments in the code - and in the answer - what did you do, how does it work -- so the value of a button would be an array of an object if there is a combo filter setup

Comment: I already explained in the answer but added few more things and updated codesandbox with comments: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-shadow-p7zx2 let me know what is preventing you from accepting the answer?